# Cannot find column in crawled property name

Tags: search, sharepoint-server, crawled-property

I had created a customed site column with the name **Color_Country**.

I need to add this column to managed properties. I started 3 times of "full crawl" for the web application (doesn't for all crawls, just for this web app), but I cannot find this column in crawled property name.
[image]

Should I start all crawls ?

Does column name is not valiated in crawled property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order the column to be picked and create crawled property, there should be at least one valid value associated with it.

So add some data and then do a full crawl.

Note - in some cases I obeserved fixing this by restarting the search Windows service.